# How come you can't enable "DEBUG_STACKOVERFLOW" when configuring a 64 bit kernel?

Tags: linux, configuration, debugging, 64bit

I'm using menuconfig to setup a linux kernel for debugging, but why does it seem that DEBUG_STACKOVERFLOW only works for 32 bit systems? [image]

As you can seen in the screenshot, enabling HAVE_DEBUG_STACKOVERFLOW requires the system to be 32 bit. Is this because it's enabled by default when compiling for 64 bit systems? Google is not leading me to any answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x86_64 used to have stack overflow checks, but they were [removed once guard pages were added to all the stack types](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=117ed45485413b1977bfc638c32bf5b01d53c62b). Guard pages provide reliable overflow protection, without needing extra checks, so the stack overflow checks were redundant.